# ImportError: cannot import name defaultdict

Tags: python, defaultdict

I'm getting this really strange `ImportError` when running `from collections import defaultdict`:

```
ImportError: cannot import name defaultdict
```

I'm running python 2.7, and the strange part is that in other parts of my application this exact same import line succeeds.

I thought maybe that's a circular import, but it doesn't make much sense when it comes to built-in python modules.

Any ideas why I get this error?

Comment: Replace the offending import with `import collections; raise ImportError(collections.__file__)` to display what module is actually being loaded. (This is just a general verification that will probably confirm what the answers have already suggested.) (if you're curious, I used an `ImportError` instead of a `print` statement since you've already confirmed that the `ImportError` is visible, so I don't have to worry about an I/O redirections intercepting the message.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably have a module named 'collections' in your project.

Try renaming this module in your project.

Comment: @Tzach, After the rename, make sure that there is no remaining `pyc` file.

Answer (score 2):

Check that you have your own version of `collections.py` in python module search path.

It will prevent importing of the standard module `collections`.

You can confirm that by using following statements:

```
import collections
print(collections)  # => This will print the module information. (esp. path)
```

Answer (score 0):

most probably you have name clashes.
Try to rename your module or method.
In Python Programming Standarts, Python puts underscore for name clashes you can also do that(http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments).