# ImportError: cannot import name defaultdict (nltk, python2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk, importerror

When I'm trying to use **nltk** with **python2.7** which is no longer supported by nltk -- so I'd to reinstall an older version (`nltk==3.0.0`) which was mentioned here: [Invalid syntax on importing nltk in python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61560956/invalid-syntax-on-importing-nltk-in-python-2-7/61561261#61561261)
I've a code which is written in older python version and hence I've to use 2.7 instead of the latest version.
I've attached a screenshot of the error that I keep getting. I've tried this [ImportError: cannot import name defaultdict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25288315/importerror-cannot-import-name-defaultdict)  which asks to remove any `collections.py` file that I have which I don't.

What I also did was to look up for the `collections.py` file in the nltk folder and then copied it locally so that I can make an edit using `cp /home/liza/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/collections.py collections.py` code and then commented the lines that were giving errors and copied the changed file back in the ntlk folder using similar command after deleting the original file but even after doing all this, nltk code just didn't work:(

**Error traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "lda_model.py", line 12, in <module> import preprocess_data

File "/home/liza/Desktop/Food-CV-HCI/Transformed LDA/DF-LDA-0.1.2/example/preprocess_data.py", line 8, in <module>
    from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer, SnowballStemmer

File "/home/liza/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 103, in <module>
    from nltk.collocations import *

File "/home/liza/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/collocations.py", line 37, in <module>
    from nltk.probability import FreqDist

File "/home/liza/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/probability.py", line 47, in <module>
    from collections import defaultdict

File "/home/liza/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/collections.py", line 13, in <module>
    from collections import defaultdict, deque, Counter
ImportError: cannot import name defaultdict
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you replace the screenshot with text of the error traceback? [Screenshots of errors are recommended against](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: What is the exact Python version you're working with (`python --version`)? This looks like a name collision between the standard library and a previous file that existed in nltk.

Comment: Thanks. I've replaced the screenshot with the text of error traceback.
I do think there is some collision but I'm unable to figure out what exactly. 
Python version is `Python 2.7.17`